# sqlite + python using a WHERE ... IN as a parameter > 999 --- or just escape

Tags: python, sqlite

consider this pseudo code:

```
items = ["aaa", "bbb", "cc%'`cc"]
sql = "select * from table where item IN (?)"
sqlite3.execute( sql, (items, ) )
```

this will fail:

```
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

There are many Q&A about it here in StackOverflow.

Some answer that you can pre-generate a param-list as this '?,?,?...'  by ','.join(len(items)*['?'].

besides being awkward and unreadable answer, it will fail if the list of items > 999.

1. Is there a way around that limitation?
2. If not, how can I escape ("quote") a string in pysqlite?

i'd expect to build something like:

```
escaped_items = map(sqlite3.escape, items)
sqlite3.execute( sql, (escaped_items, ) )
```

Comment: If you end up with item lists of 1000 elements or more you should not even **think** about using `col IN (...)`. Use a temporary table instead.

Comment: In other words, pre-generate the parameter list only for a small number of parameters, a few dozen at most. After that, use a temporary table to hold all those values and use a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing such a large parameter list would be inefficient.

Just create a temporary table to hold the values:

```
sqlite3.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE items(x)")
sqlite3.executemany("INSERT INTO items VALUES (?)", items);
sqlite3.execute("SELECT ... WHERE item in items")
...
sqlite3.execute("DROP TABLE items")
```